# Does xCode8 have migration tools for Swift 2.2?

Tags: swift, xcode, operating-system

Come into some issues and wanted to get some feedback/ideas on a migration. Looking at xCode8 (Currently 7) but have some 2.2 but doing more on 2.3.

Does xCode8 have migration tools for Swift 2.2?

Comment: https://swift.org/migration-guide/

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your swift 2.3 and 2.2 code to swift 3.0.. and swift 2.2 to 2.3. But you cannot migrate to 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't, Xcode 8 supports **Swift 2.3** and **Swift 3.0**.

[image]

Checkout the [migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no migration back to swift 2.2 in xcode 8. If your code is in swift 2.2 or earlier version then it automatically ask to migrate your code into swift 2.3 or swift 3.